# Finding the relation between coefficients of quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

[image]

## My attempt:

I could prove  $|c| < 1$.

As it given that $f\lt 1$, so $f(0)\lt 1$.

I have solved using triangular inequality. Is there any other way?
ans is ABCD

Comment: ans is A,B,C,D .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the boundaries $x=0$ and $x=1$ the inequality corresponds to

- $x=0 \implies |c|\le 1$
- $x=1 \implies |a+b+c|\le 1 \implies 0\le|a+b|\le 2$

Let wlog $a \ge 0$, since the extrema values are also reached at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ we need to consider $3$ cases:

$1) \quad 0\le-\frac{b}{2a}\le1 \iff -2a\le b\le 0$

- $x=1 \implies |a+b+c|\le 1 \implies 0\le|a+b|\le 2 \implies 0\le a \le 2 \land -4\le b \le 0$
- $x=-\frac{b}{2a} \implies \left|\frac {b^2} {4a}-\frac{b^2}{2a}+c\right|\le 1\implies 0\le \left|-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right|\le 2\implies 0\le b^2 \le 8a\implies -2\sqrt {2a}\le b \le 0$

and since

- $2\sqrt {2a}=2a \iff \sqrt {2a}=a\iff a=2$

we have

- $0\le a \le 2$
- $-4\le b \le 0$

$2) \quad b\ge 0$

- $x=1 \implies |a+b+c|\le 1 \implies 0\le a+b \le 2 $

and since $a \ge 0$ we have

- $0\le a \le 2$
- $-2\le b \le  2$

$3) \quad b\le -2a $

- $x=1 \implies |a+b+c|\le 1 \implies 0\le |a+b| \le 2 \implies -2\le a+b \le 0$

and we have

- $0\le a \le 2$
- $-4 \le b \le 0$

Therefore all options are correct.

Comment: all options are true, have done them using triangular inequality

Comment: @ashishdeosingh Yes you are right! I've fixed the derivation and some typo.

Comment: @gimusi  I think the OP means that he had already solved this using the triangle inequality and was, in-fact, looking for some alternate approach. That may also explain why he has not accepted your answer (though that may have something to do with bit knowing the ropes of the site / laziness( more likely, IMHO), since he has also consistently avoided use of MathJax, despite being suggested to do so by other users).

Comment: +1 for explaining in detail though :-)

Comment: @DevashishKaushik Thanks for the appreciation! Bye